# Apache htaccess redirect only root without change url root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, yii2

I have a complex situation:
myproject.com: is working fine both http and https running Yii2 web application

My client wants to integrate WordPress only for the main page, maintaining the rest of Yii2 web application

I create on the same host a new environment called wp.myproject.com where another user is building WordPress new main page (with other 2/3 static page for example the classic "contact us" or "about us")

What i need is that when visitors go on https://myproject.com it redirect to wp.myproject.com but the url must remain https://myproject.com

I search alot over the net but doesn't find a good solution.
Can you help me? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but you need to use `mod_proxy`. Before you do this, please take note of the security risks that this proposes: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Also be aware, that `mod_proxy` needs to be enabled on your server for this to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://wp.myproject.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

This will take either `www.myproject.com` and `myproject.com` redirect it to `wp.myproject.com/anything` but keep the original URL.

You might want to change HTTP to HTTPs, dependent on if you use SSL or not.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: thank's Joe, i try as you suggest, but it redirects all request to wp.myproject.com and doesn't keep the original URL.
I want that myproject.com/user/login for example doesn't redirect to wp.myproject.com

Comment: You've enabled `mod_proxy` in your `httpd.conf`? This has to be done or it will not work.